# ionic2 Storing Array of Objects in Storage

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm following the following example in ionic2 storage: https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

I'm fetching an object param from a form page, add it to myBOTs variable and saving the whole array of objects so I can use it to populate the list when the page gets refreshed.

what i did in constructor was simply to call on storage to find current values to populate the list.

```
id: any;
icons: string[];
myBOTs: Array <{type: string,BOTdate: string, setReminder: boolean, icon: string}>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
    this.myBOTs=[];
    this.storage.get('myBOTs').then((values)=>{
        if(values!==null){
            for(let i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
                this.myBOTs.push({
                    type: values[i].type,
                    BOTdate: values[i].BOTdate,
                    icon: this.icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.icons.length)],
                    setReminder: values[i].setReminder
                })
            }               
        }
    })
}
```

the problem lies below where **this.storage.set('myBOTs',this.myBOTs)**. only the last object of the array gets saved when i try to console.log(values) retrieving the data after the .set.

I am thinking maybe ionic storage cannot store array of objects in .set?  or if not, what seems to be the problem?

```
ionViewDidLoad(){
    if(this.navParams.get('type')!==undefined){
        let addedBOT = [];
        addedBOT['type'] = this.navParams.get('type');
        addedBOT['BOTdate'] = this.navParams.get('BOTdate');
        addedBOT['setReminder'] = this.navParams.get('setReminder');
        this.myBOTs.push({
            type: addedBOT['type'],
            BOTdate: addedBOT['BOTdate'],
            icon: this.icons[1],
            setReminder: addedBOT['setReminder']
        })
        this.storage.set('myBOTs',this.myBOTs);
        this.storage.get('myBOTs').then((values)=>{
            console.log(values);
        })          
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize this.myBOTs? Is this a blank array? When you push to it, are you sure it has a previous value in this array? By the way, this.storage.set is async, as the get. So you have no guarantee that the console.log(values) occurs after the set method has finished.

Comment: yes. I noted that storage.set is async. But yes, the results after refreshing is still just the last object of the array.

Comment: Is this the line? myBOTs: Array <{type: string,BOTdate: string, setReminder: boolean, icon: string}>;

Comment: and this line?: this.myBOTs=[];

Comment: If there are values in storage, it will be added in the constructor with .get. If not, it will be just an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it.

The problem lies with both constructor and ionViewDidLoad gets called up asynchronously when the page loads. This results in the data push from the form page getting added to this.myBOTs first before the results are fetched and loaded from storage in the list in constructor.

So here is my solution. What I did was to add the code to functions and add a callback to my list generating function before the form data gets added to the list.

```
id: any;
icons: string[];
myBOTs: Array <{type: string,BOTdate: string, setReminder: boolean, icon: string}>;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
    this.myBOTs=[];
    let e = this;
    this.generate_list(function(){
        e.add_item();
    })
}
```

list generation function to set up previous list items from storage..

```
generate_list(callback){
    this.storage.get('myBOTs').then((values)=>{
        if(values!==null){
            for(let i = 0;i < values.length;i++){
                this.myBOTs.push({
                    type: values[i].type,
                    BOTdate: values[i].BOTdate,
                    icon: this.icons[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.icons.length)],
                    setReminder: values[i].setReminder
                })
            }               
        }
        callback();
    })
}
```

then add new item from data from navParams

```
add_item(){
    if(this.navParams.get('type')!==undefined){
        let addedBOT = [];
        addedBOT['type'] = this.navParams.get('type');
        addedBOT['BOTdate'] = this.navParams.get('BOTdate');
        addedBOT['setReminder'] = this.navParams.get('setReminder');
        this.myBOTs.push({
            type: addedBOT['type'],
            BOTdate: addedBOT['BOTdate'],
            icon: this.icons[1],
            setReminder: addedBOT['setReminder']
        })
        this.storage.set('myBOTs',this.myBOTs);
        console.log('storage added');        
    }    
}
```

works out perfectly. Might help out someone as this is a pretty common scenario.